# how do I resolve it? running command sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Tags: updates, ppa

```
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                              
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease              
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease     
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release

  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done    
                          
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Asked a million times...

Comment: Did you look at https://launchpad.net/~boost-latest/+archive/ubuntu/ppa  (*taken from your pasted details*), it's pretty clear that something that supported releases from 2013 & earlier has no support for anything as modern as 22.04 (a 2022-April release). PPAs are 3rd party *personal package archives* so it's on you to perform security checks on them; an *abandoned* PPA would have worried me & I'd not have added it.  I suggest removing it.

Answer (score 3):

In the future, you should search Google the PPA (google "ppa:boost-latest/ppa" for example) and one of the first results should be the [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/%7Eboost-latest/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Visit the launchpad page before you install the PPA. Then, scroll down to the **Overview of published packages** section and click on the dropdown menu for **Published in: Any Series** (see screenshot below). This will display all supported Ubuntu versions. If you do not see your Ubuntu version listed, like **Focal** for 20.04 or **Jammy** for 22.04, then you cannot use the PPA as your version is not supported.

[image: screenshot of the launchpad page and the dropdown menu for Published in shows saucy raring quantail and a few others but there are no newer, currently supported versions of ubuntu are listed]

##### Now, to fix the problem.

First, run the following commands to uninstall the broken PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:boost-latest/ppa
sudo apt update
```

You may notice that this is the same as the command used to add the repository but the `-r` option is added to ***remove*** the PPA instead.

##### If you still want or need the latest C++ BOOST library:

Another quick search on Google for "ubuntu libboost PPA"  brought up [a newer PPA that supports all the newer versions of Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/%7Emhier/+archive/ubuntu/libboost-latest) like Jammy, Focal, Kinetic, etc.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mhier/libboost-latest
sudo apt update
```

It should be noted that it's not recommended to install third party software repositories from random people off of the internet. Security is based on trust and you should only install software from a third party if you are willing to place your trust in that person to run their code on your system.

Also, there may be other alternatives. There might be another PPA from another person or organization so again, search on Google and you might find something better. You may also find examples of other people using this particular PPA with success and that may be one reason to have at least some confidence that it might work fine.

But keep in mind that people frequently use third party software on Windows and this is one of the many reasons windows has so many viruses.